# Can't boot arm64 cloud image with qemu

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, openstack, cloud-init

I first downloaded [ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-arm64.img](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04/release/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-arm64.img), then I started it with qemu

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -m 2G -M virt -cpu max -bios /usr/share/qemu-efi-aarch64/QEMU_EFI.fd -drive if=none,file=ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-arm64.img,id=hd0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -device e1000,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:5555-:22 -nographic -cdrom cidata.iso
```

And it just fails here:

```
[  159.518738] EXT4-fs (vda1): re-mounted. Opts: discard,errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

This error is unexpected, is the image broken?

Comment: I reproduced the error, but don't know what caused it :/